# inserting to multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to insert variables to the array by using foreach loop. This is the foreach loop im trying to implement with

```
foreach($rows as &$url) {
      $link = array("url");
      array_push($url, "hello World"); 
}
```

And this is the result I get.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [id] => RT
            [name] => root
            [parent] => 0
            [0] => hello World
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 2
            [id] => CI
            [name] => Civil & Interior Works
            [parent] => 1
            [0] => hello World
        )

)
```

but i would like the  result to be like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 1
            [id] => RT
            [name] => root
            [parent] => 0
            [url] => hello World
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_id] => 2
            [id] => CI
            [name] => Civil & Interior Works
            [parent] => 1
            [url] => hello World
        )

)
```

If i pass the variable  `$link = array("url");` to `array_push($link, "hello World");` nothing happens.

if I remove the referance from the `foreach($rows as &$url)` the loop does not work at all. Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a value under the required key:

```
foreach($rows as &$row) {
    $row['url'] = "hello World";
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked... so array_push was not required ??

Comment: `array_push` adds an element in the end of array, it doesn't care about keys. If you need a specific key - use `['key']` syntax.

Comment: I noticed something... if i use `&$row` referance ... I lose one loop... the last element item inserted dis not picked up.

Comment: Create an example of your code and ask a new question.